# Using regex to parse data between delimeter and ending at a specified substring

Tags: regex, ruby

I'm trying to parse out the names from a bunch of semi-unpredictable strings. More specifically, I'm using ruby, but I don't think that should matter much. This is a contrived example but some example strings are:

```
Eagles vs Bears
NFL Matchup: Philadelphia Eagles VS Chicago Bears TUNE IN
NFL Matchup: Philadelphia Eagles VS Chicago Bears - TUNE IN
Philadelphia Eagles vs Chicago Bears - NFL Match
Phil.Eagles vs Chic.Bears
3agles vs B3ars
```

The regex I've come up with is

`([0-9A-Z .]*) vs ([0-9A-Z .]*)(?:[ -:]*tune)?/i`

but in the case of "NFL Matchup: Philadelphia Eagles VS Chicago Bears TUNE IN" I'm receiving `Chicago Bears TUNE` as the second match. I'm trying to remove "tune in" so it's in it's own group.

I thought that by adding   `(?:[ -:]*tune)?` it would separate the ending portion of the expression the same way that having `vs` in the middle was able to, but that doesnt seem to be the case. If I remove the `?` at the end, it matches correctly for the above example, but it no longer matches for `Eagles vs Bears`

If anyone could help me, I would greatly appreciate it if you could breakdown your regex piece by piece.

Comment: You [do not get `TUNE IN`](https://rubular.com/r/VQjvyrDEYnYkMe) as the match because `in` is not prt of the regex.

Comment: When you give examples please show the desired results (even when they are obvious to you).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can capture the second group up to a `-`, `:` or `tune` preceded with zero or more whitespaces or till end of the line while making the second group pattern lazy:

```
([\w .]*) vs ([\w .]*?)(?=\s*(?:[:-]|tune|$))
```

See the [regex demo](https://rubular.com/r/3tm63jnzVzpnpp).

*Details*:

- `([\w .]*)` - Group 1: zero or more word, space or `.` chars as many as possible
- `vs` - a `vs` string
- `([\w .]*?)` - Group 2: zero or more word, space or `.` chars as few as possible
- `(?=\s*(?:[:-]|tune|$))` - a positive lookahead that requires the following pattern to appear immediately to the right of the current location:

  - `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
  - `(?:[:-]|tune|$)` -  `:` or `-`, `tune` or end of a line.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regular expression which I have expressed in [free-spacing mode](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Regexp.html) to make it self-documenting (search for "Free-Spacing Mode" at the link).

```
 rgx = /
       (?: |\A)              # match space or beginning of string
       (?<team1>             # begin capture group team1
         (?<team>            # begin capture group team
           (?<word>          # begin capture group word
             (?:\p{Lu}|\d)   # word begins with an uppercase letter or digit
             (?:\p{Ll}|\d)+  # ...followed by 1+ lowercase letters or digits
           )                 # end capture group word
           (?:               # begin non-capture group
             [ .]            # match a space or period
             \g<word>        # match another word
           )*                # end non-capture group and execute 1+ times
         )                   # end capture group team
       )                     # end capture group team1
       [ ]+                  # match one or more spaces
       (?:VS|vs)             # match literal
       [ ]+                  # match one or more spaces
       (?<team2>             # begin capture group team2
         \g<team>            # match the second team name
       )                     # end capture group team2
       (?:                   # begin non-capture group
         [ ]                 # match a space
         (?:                 # begin non-capture group
           (?:-[ ])?         # optionally match literal
           TUNE[ ]IN         # match literal
           |                 # or
           -[ ]NFL[ ]Match   # match literal
         )                   # end inner capture group 
       )?                    # end outer non-capture group and make it optional
       \z                    # match end of string
       /x                    # free-spacing regex definition mode
```

```
examples = [
  "Eagles vs Bears",
  "NFL Matchup: Philadelphia Eagles VS Chicago Bears TUNE IN",
  "NFL Matchup: Philadelphia Eagles VS Chicago Bears - TUNE IN",
  "Philadelphia Eagles vs Chicago Bears - NFL Match",
  "Phil.Eagles vs Chic.Bears",
  "3agles vs B3ars"
]
```

```
examples.map do |s|
  m = s.match(rgx)
  [m[:team1], m[:team2]]
end
  #=> [["Eagles", "Bears"],
  #    ["Philadelphia Eagles", "Chicago Bears"],
  #    ["Philadelphia Eagles", "Chicago Bears"],
  #    ["Philadelphia Eagles", "Chicago Bears"],
  #    ["Phil.Eagles", "Chic.Bears"],
  #    ["3agles", "B3ars"]]
```

See [Regexp#match](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Regexp.html#method-i-match) and [MatchData#[]](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/MatchData.html#method-i-5B-5D).

Note that `\g<word>` and `\g<team>` effectively copy the code contained in the capture groups `word` and `team`, respectively. These are called "Subexpression Calls". For additional information search for that term at [Regexp](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Regexp.html). There are two advantages to using subroutine calls: less code is needed and the opportunities for coding errors is reduced.